# Get the user who clicked on the button in the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have added the button into spreadsheet and assigned the script to it. Is there a way to determine the user's email of person that clicked it? Script edits the data so probably `onEdit` trigger should work, however function  with `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` set by this trigger doesn't recognize the user.

Thank you

Comment: Is this in a domain or a public side script?

Comment: if you are using a "normal " gmail account it is not possible to obtain the user's email when he accesses the spreadsheet. In business or education version you can.

Comment: @Sergeinsas oh, I didn't know that. That sucks. However thank you for info. Just tested it and you are right.

Comment: I've made a workaround below, that you can use with normal gmail accounts also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible with normal gmail accounts, with this workaround!

I'm using some protection functionality that reveals the user and owner of the document and I'm storing it in the properties for better performance. Have fun with it!

```
function onEdit(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("User Email is " + getUserEmail());
}

function getUserEmail() {
  var userEmail = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("userEmail");
  if(!userEmail) {
    var protection = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("A1").protect();
    // tric: the owner and user can not be removed
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    var editors = protection.getEditors();
    if(editors.length === 2) {
      var owner = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getOwner();
      editors.splice(editors.indexOf(owner),1); // remove owner, take the user
    }
    userEmail = editors[0];
    protection.remove();
    // saving for better performance next run
    PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty("userEmail",userEmail);
  }
  return userEmail;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, splice function returned (I don't know why) always mail of the owner, but in debug I can see that other mails are in the array.

Comment: That's right. The splice function removes the owner, so that's the value it returns as well, if you would log it.

Comment: What about other attributes? I hope to get username but couldn't find a key to get it.